# Conversion process of lanolin to 7-Dehydrocholestrol

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the Chemical process to convert lanolin to 7-Dehydrocholestrol?
I don't know about the chemcial reaction, if I get the process I can try in lab scale.

Comment: Lanolin is a very complex mixture. I think you main problem is likely to be isolating the precursor lanolin alcohol is a decent level of purity.

Comment: Hydrolysis of lanolin to lanolin alcohols  https://patents.google.com/patent/US2824143A/en

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of lanolin to 7-dehydrocholestrol is an important procedure in the production of vitamin D.

Lanolin is converted to cholesterol by a method which comprises of following steps:

1. dissociating cholesterol from lanolin by transesterification
   reaction;
2. performing short-path distillation to obtain cholesterol crude
   product
3. purifying by silica gel column chromatography
4. crystallizing to obtain refined cholesterol with purity higher than
   95% and yield higher than 70%.

The extracted cholesterol is converted to 7-dehydrocholesterol and then treated with UV light to produce vitamin D3. The method has such advantages as high product consumption, little pollution, simple process and easy operation, thus is suitable for mass production.

**References**

1. https://patents.google.com/patent/CN1958596A/en
2. https://patents.google.com/patent/CN1263769C/en
3. https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biofiles/nutrition-research.html